# How to solve the equation $3x=33 \pmod{100}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The equation is $ 3x\equiv 33\pmod{100}$

---

I factored the 100 as $2^2 \cdot 5^2$ then I got the system of equations: $$3x \equiv 33\pmod 4$$ $$3x \equiv33\pmod{25}$$

---

then I transformed the equivalences into this two: $$3x \equiv 2 \pmod 4$$ $$3x\equiv8 \pmod{25}$$

---

And from there I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: No need for CRT, simply cancel $\,c = 3\,$ as in the linked dupe.

Comment: There is one obvious solution. And other solutions must satisfy $3(x_2-x_1) \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ and $3(x_2-x_1) \equiv 0 \pmod{25}$...